# Keras - How to compute a double sum?

Tags: numpy, keras

I am using keras and I have to implement a double sum like [this one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lWeP.gif)

where f is a (?, N_f) tensor and g is is a (?, N_g) tensor. The product f*g should be a (?, N_f * N_g) tensor and the reduced double sum a (1,) tensor.

How can I implement this on Keras?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you currently compute that sum or where you want to compute it?

Comment: That's the issue. I have to compute these double sums for a custom loss and I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've ended up with:

```
def double_sum(x, y): 
    #n_x should be equal to n_y
    n_x = x.shape[1].value
    n_y = y.shape[1].value

    x_rep = K.repeat_elements(x, n_x, axis=1)
    y_tile = K.tile(y, [1, n_y])
    return K.sum(K.dot(x_rep, y_tile))
```

I hope it helps someone else in the future.